# With `quiet` kernel option in my grub entry, can I make the boot messages visible?

Tags: boot, debug

I like my machine to boot quietly, if only for aestethic reasons. Sometimes, however, [things go wrong](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2622/blank-screen-blinking-cursor-on-boot/9484#9484), and then I would like to see the boot messages. Can I switch them on during boot, i. e. without rebooting and modifying the GRUB entry?

Answer (score 3):

if you don't see your grub menu press `shift` during a boot.
if you see grub, go to the line/kernel you want to boot.
press `e` to edit the config of that kernel.
remove `quiet` and press `ctrl+x` to boot.

Comment: I know that, but that's not what I asked.

Comment: Can you tell why it's not so I can find another way

Answer (score 1):

Pressing Escape key while the system boots will hide the plymouth splash screen and show you the boot messages.

[More information can be found here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts)

Comment: It does not seem to work on my machine. What's plymouth?

Comment: Plymouth is the project name for the graphical boot process. http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth. What do you see when you press escape?

Comment: Nothing happens, it just resumes the boot process and gives me the graphical login screen. I'm using an out-of-the-box Lucid Netbook Remix