# Machine starts to blank screen with blinking underscore every time, even after restarting gdm3

Tags: boot, 20.04, gdm

I have a Dell Precision 7540 with Ubuntu 20.04. I came into a problem where my machine would boot and get to a screen with a blinking underscore. This occurred after I closed my laptop, it had a blank screen and then restarted it. I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/297080/1139619) and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1286728/1139619) worked for me, getting me to the login page and then all was fine.

However when I restart my machine the same problem occurs every time. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/2623/1139619) suggested accessing the GRUB menu. I tried to push `Shift` and `esc` when restarting and cannot access the GRUB menu.

Using the method which restarts gdm3 works fine, but I would like to avoid having to do this every time I turn my machine one. Any help would be appreciated.